# How to override default route path in web.config for asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is it possible to override the default route of asp.net mvc application by altering web.config file ?

without modifying the routeconfig.cs file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it with following work around:

Suppose, you have in your web.config an routing element with the format "controller/action".
In my RouteConfig.cs I added following code:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
  var mySection = 
    WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~").GetSection("WHATEVER_YOU_NEED");
  if (mySection != null)
  {
    // OVERRIDE WITH WEB.CONFIG
    string[] parts = mySection["YOUR_GROUP"].Split('/');
    routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new 
                { 
                   controller = parts[0], 
                   action = parts[1], 
                   id = UrlParameter.Optional 
                });
  }
  else
  {
    routes.MapRoute( ... YOUR DEFAULT ROUTE ...);         
  }
}
```